# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)

Tags: python, aes, rsa, nonce, pycryptodome

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP

file_in = open("encrypted_data.bin", "rb")

private_key = RSA.import_key(open("private.pem").read())

enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = [ file_in.read(x) for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16) ]
```

i believe the error is the number 16 at [ file_in.read(x) for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16) ]. Isn't AES supposed to be 16 bytes? I would like to understand why I am getting the error and how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: `(private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16)` is a tuple with two elements.  You call `file_in.read(x)` for each of those elements, producing a list with two elements.  You then attempt to unpack that two-element list into four variables, which of course fails.  Where were you expecting those two extra values to come from?

Comment: Oh right! But even after I changed the line to `[ file_in.read(x) for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16) ]`, it still show similar error.

Comment: Now you'll have 3 elements in your resulting list, but you still need four values.  You need to add one more call to `file_in.read(x)` to get four values.

Comment: I added another 16 and it works, thanks to you. But I also found someone use -1 for the last one. Would you mind explain this since I couldn't find the reason on google.

Comment: for the last what?  I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've seen somewhere on google someone use `[ file_in.read(x) for x in (key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16, -1) ]` but couldn't understand why.